# Microsoft Azure cognitive Services LUIS not displaying what users are entering in review end point utterances

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KuKj.png)Tried this with Both paid plans of LUIS and also the free version of LUIS not sure if i am doing something wrong or missing any settings. Any Help on this would be appriciated.

Comment: this is more of a statement, maybe a passing thought,   but its not a question!   you need to say whats wrong and why.   i.e   I have created a bot   [  this is my code ]    and ran the bot,   this should be sending user content to luis, and I expect this response,    but instead i get XXX error message.   can anyone help.      What you said is:    something doesn't work, please look at my screen

Comment: How can no match be found? There is always a top scoring intent. Utterances only show up on the review list if the top 2 scores are very close or the top score is very low.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the issue so that we can understand better what the issue is?

Comment: Apologies for confusion but When i access LUIS API URL And provide an utterance that is not available in my list of defined utterances  it matches to one of the intent and then i see that particular utterance in my LUIS portal under review end point utterances where i can confirm that LUIS identified the intent correctly and i can mark it as correct or else i can change to a different intent. these utterances are not showing up when i integrated Luis with a Facebook messenger chat bot. I have not chance to correct what it predicts.

Comment: My issue is resolved now i can see all that users enters in the review end point section after i started using the V2.0 version of LUIS. Thanks All for your time in looking into this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue when i was using the LUIS Version 1.0 from my node js code.
I was unable to see the utterences in review end point utterences.

After changing the version in code to 2.0 all started working.